# Lattices as invertible module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $E$ be an etale algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.  In other words, $E$ is a finite sum of number fields. Let $L$ be a lattice in $E$, and $R$ the order associated to $L$.  More explicitly, $$R=\{ e\in E\mid eL\subset L\}.$$
Then is it true that $L$ is an invertible $R$-module?

I know this is true in several cases.  For example, if $E$ is quadratic imaginary field (Serge Lang, Elliptic functions, Theorem 9, chaper 8), or if $R$ is the maximal order in $E$ (Then $R$ is a product of Dedkind Domains).

More generally, I am wondering if the following is true. Let $R$ be a 1-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay ring with total fractional ring $E$.  Let $I\subset E$ be a fractional ideal (i.e., a finitely generated $R$-module) containing a nonzero divisor of $E$. Is it true that 
the condition $\{ e\in E\mid e I\subset I\}=R$ implies that $I$ is an invertible $R$-module?

Comment: I think mathoverflow will be perfect for this question :).